# onActivityCreated is deprecated, how to properly use LifecycleObserver?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-lifecycle

Google deprecate fragment’s onActivityCreated() on Android and recommend to use LifeCycleObserver:

```
 To get a callback specifically when a Fragment activity's
     * {@link Activity#onCreate(Bundle)} is called, register a
     * {@link androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver} on the Activity's
     * {@link Lifecycle} in {@link #onAttach(Context)}, removing it when it receives the
     * {@link Lifecycle.State#CREATED} callback.
```

So I try to make it in recommended way, but only state I can observe in Logcat is just **State: INITIALIZED**.

```
 private lateinit var lifecycleObserver: LifecycleObserver

 override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)

    hostActivity = context as HostActivity

    lifecycleObserver = object : LifecycleObserver {

        @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
        fun onCreate() {
            Logger.tag("SOME-TAG")d("State: ${lifecycle.currentState}")

            if(lifecycle.currentState.isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.CREATED)) {
                Logger.tag("SOME-TAG").d("CREATED")
                hostActivity.lifecycle.removeObserver(lifecycleObserver)
            }
        }
    }

    hostActivity.lifecycle.addObserver(lifecycleObserver)
}
```

What is wrong in code above?

**UPDATE 1**: Looks like I forgot to use hostActivity.lifecycle.currentState and checked fragment's lifecycle instead of Activities lifecycle.

**UPDATE 2**: Suggested by Google approach not worked for 
1 Host activity and 2 fragments when you click back button from one to another, cause onAttach never called, but onActivityCreated called.

Comment: Did you find a solution for the back issue? I have the same issue with the solution suggested by google. Wonder if I misunderstood what they said and actually updating the toolbar should not be happening in there and it should be tied to a fragment lifecycle instead.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

All I needed was `onActivityCreated(...)`, hence I did implement an observer that:

- Automatically removes itself (using `.removeObserver(...)`).
- Then calls passed callback (`update()`).

I did it in next way:

```
class MyActivityObserver(
    private val update: () -> Unit
) : DefaultLifecycleObserver {

    override fun onCreate(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        super.onCreate(owner)
        owner.lifecycle.removeObserver(this)
        update()
    }
}
```

and use it in fragments onAttach (or another lifecycle method) like:

```
myActivity.lifecycle.addObserver(MyActivityObserver {
    myOnActivityCreated()
})
```

But to support older Android API levels, either your `Activity` needs to be of `androidx`'s `AppCompatActivity` type (which has `getLifecycle()`), or, use a simple `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")`.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/DefaultLifecycleObserver#onCreate(androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner) - This method will be called after the LifecycleOwner's onCreate method returns.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that, if I make a multi-triggering callback solution (f.e. onResume - this state can be called more than 1 time within a lifecycle), then the callback will work only once, because after the first triggering, it will be unsubscribed? Maybe, better is to make unsubscription in the latest lifecycle callback 'onDestroy'?

Answer (score 53):

As per the changelog [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.3.0-alpha02)

> The `onActivityCreated()` method is now deprecated. Code touching the
> fragment's view should be done in `onViewCreated()` (which is called
> immediately before `onActivityCreated()`) and other initialization code
> should be in `onCreate()`. To receive a callback specifically when the
> activity's `onCreate()` is complete, a `LifeCycleObserver` should be
> registered on the activity's Lifecycle in `onAttach()`, and removed once
> the `onCreate()` callback is received.

You can do something like this in your fragment class:

```
class MyFragment : Fragment(), LifecycleObserver {
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
    fun onCreated() {
        // ... Your Logic goes here ...
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        activity?.lifecycle?.addObserver(this)
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        activity?.lifecycle?.removeObserver(this)
        super.onDetach()
    }
}
```

Comment: Unlike normal `onActivityCreated()` that is called after `onViewCreated()`, the `onCreated()` method is called before `onCreateView()`

Comment: d= (◕‿↼ ) Too bad! The `@OnLifecycleEvent` notation is deprecated nowadays as well, and docs suggest to use `DefaultLifecycleObserver` or `LifecycleEventObserver` instead.

Comment: (Someone tell Google  to deside once forever, and not just write whatever, without any standard.)

Answer (score 9):

You can consider the Lifecycle.State as the nodes in a graph and Lifecycle.Event as the edges between these nodes.

So you will never reached the State.Created on your ON_CREATE function.

**Solution**

```
class YourFragment : Fragment(), LifecycleObserver {
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
    fun onCreated(){
        Log.i("tag","reached the State.Created")
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        lifecycle.addObserver(this)
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        lifecycle.removeObserver(this)
    }
}
```

**For more details**

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle#lc

Comment: DEPRECATED solution

Comment: `@OnLifecycleEvent` DEPRECATE!!

Answer (score 7):

**Update on 17 Sep, 2023**

`launchWhenCreated` is deprecated(see the detailed [blog post](https://manuelvivo.dev/coroutines-addrepeatingjob)) as it leads to wasted resources(not in this case though as in this example we are not continuously subscribed to any resource) below code using `launchWhenCreated` can be replicated with the help of `repeatOnLifecycle`

```kotlin
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    requireActivity().lifecycleScope.launch {
        requireActivity().lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.CREATED) {
            setupActionbar()
        }
    }
}
```

How does it work? `lifecycleScope.launch` launches a scope with `suspend` block in the activity lifecycle. This scope is required as `repeatOnLifecycle` is a suspending function which can only be called inside `suspend` block. Here `repeatOnLifecycle` automatically stops the job when lifecycle goes out of the `State.CREATED` and then relaunches it when it comes back to the `State.CREATED`

**Original post**

The best way to solve the issue is to use `lifecycleScope` which is present in the activity lifecycle. Below is the code snippet

```kotlin
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    activity?.lifecycleScope?.launchWhenCreated {
        setupActionbar()
    }
}
```

How does it work? `launchWhenXxx` runs the launch block when it automatically reaches the specified state(in this case it is Created) and if the lifecycle goes to the destroyed state it cancels the launched coroutine automatically. **Internally `lifecycleScope` uses `Dispatchers.Main.immediate` and hence there is no penalty for thread switching**

Pros of this approach are the following:

1. You don't have to manually maintain the registering and deregistering of the observer
2. No need to overwrite two lifecycle methods

You have to latest activity and fragment dependencies to use lifecycleScope attached to the lifecycle

Comment: launchWhenCreated will be deprecated soon, it is better to not use it

Comment: @Sever No issue I will always update this post with the latest technology.

Comment: also deprecated

Comment: Hi, @PedroVarela updated the code. Really thanks for the reminder. Please let me know if you have any feedback

Answer (score 2):

`onActivityCreated` is deprecated in API level 28.

> use `onViewCreated` for code touching the view created by
> `onCreateView` and `onCreate` for other initialization. To get a
> callback specifically when a Fragment activity's `onCreate` is called,
> register a `androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver` on the Activity's
> Lifecycle in `onAttach`, removing it when it receives the `CREATED`
> callback.

The annotation `@OnLifecycleEvent` is deprecated too.

> This annotation required the usage of code generation or reflection,
> which should be avoided. Use `DefaultLifecycleObserver` or
> `LifecycleEventObserver` instead.

**The simplest solution:** In general, in most cases the `onActivityCreated` issue can be resolved by moving the code to `onViewCreated`. If that doesn't work for you, continue reading down.

====================================================================

So, to fix the issue with the deprecated `onActivityCreated` and `OnLifecycleEvent` annotation you should do the following:

1. Implement `DefaultLifecycleObserver`.
2. Register your class as observer in `onAttach()`.
3. Override `onCreate(owner: LifecycleOwner)` and move your code from `onActivityCreated` in it.
4. De-register the observer when the `CREATE` event is received in `onCreate()`

See Kotlin and Java examples below:

## Kotlin:

```
class YourFragment : Fragment(), DefaultLifecycleObserver {

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        // Register your class as observer
        activity?.lifecycle?.addObserver(this)
    }

    override fun onCreate(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        super<DefaultLifecycleObserver>.onCreate(owner)
        // Remove the observer
        activity?.lifecycle?.removeObserver(this)

        //Move here your code from onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) 

    }

}
```

## Java:

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment implements DefaultLifecycleObserver {

    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        // Register your class as observer
        if (getActivity() != null) {
            getActivity().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner) {
        DefaultLifecycleObserver.super.onCreate(owner);
        // Remove the observer
        if (getActivity() != null) {
            getActivity().getLifecycle().removeObserver(this);
        }

        //Move here your code from onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) 

    }
```

**IMPORTANT**: Note that `onActivityCreated` is called after `onCreateView`, but `DefaultLifecycleObserver.onCreate` is called before `onCreateView`. So, if until now you were using in `onActivityCreated` something initialised in `onCreateView`, you'll have to move it somewhere else. E.g. in `onViewCreated()`.