# DataBinding doesn't update value when changing LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-livedata, android-databinding

I want the value to increase when I press the button and write it in the `textview`.
However, the code below shows the increasing value as Log
But, on screen, the value in `textview` does not change.
I'm not sure what's wrong. Please let me know if you know.

**Fragment.kt**

```
class SettingFragment : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = SettingFragment()
        private val TAG = "SettingFragment"
    }

    private lateinit var viewModel: SettingViewModel
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentSettingBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_setting, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(SettingViewModel::class.java)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        binding.button.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        viewModel.increase()
        Log.d(TAG, "Log Data" + viewModel.testInt.value)
    }

}
```

**FragmentViewModel**

```
class SettingViewModel : ViewModel() {


    val testInt: MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData()

    init {
        testInt.value = 0
    }

    fun increase() {
        testInt.value = testInt.value?.plus(1)
    }
}
```

**fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.ui.setting.SettingViewModel" />
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".ui.setting.SettingFragment">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{String.valueOf(viewModel.testInt)}" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.example.ui.setting.SettingViewModel" />
```

This `viewModel` variable doesn't bind to a certain variable programmatically. So, when the value incremented, it won't reflect to the layout.

To fix this set the fragment's `viewModel` to this value:

```
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(SettingViewModel::class.java)
    binding.viewModel = viewModel // <<<<< Here is the change
    binding.lifecycleOwner = this
    binding.button.setOnClickListener(this)
```

**Side note:**

You shouldn't use `onActivityCreated()` as it's is [deprecated as of API level 28](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)); you can normally its part of code to `onCreateView()`. And you can [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61306719/onactivitycreated-is-deprecated-how-to-properly-use-lifecycleobserver) for other alternatives.

Comment: I've been thinking about why not for a long time, but thank you for letting me know. Thanks, you save my time :)